# Create dummy asyncio.Task

Tags: task, python-asyncio

How can I create dummy Task object that will be immediately done?

#### Why?

I often check if `task is not None and task.done()` just to check if another task can be spawn and feel it's a boilerplate that can be avoided:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self._do_something_task: Optional[asyncio.Task] = None

async def _do_something(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    # something

def trigger_do_something(self):
    if self._do_something_task is not None and self._do_something_task.done():
        asyncio.create_task(self._do_something())
```

Currently my workaround is:

```py
def __init__(self):
    self._do_something_task: asyncio.Task = asyncio.create_task(asyncio.sleep(0))

async def _do_something(self):
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    # something

def trigger_do_something(self):
    if self._do_something_task.done():
        asyncio.create_task(self._do_something())
```

but I feel its not very readable at the first glance.

Comment: You seem to have both a method called `_do_something` defined on the class and a `_do_something` attribute on the instance. Is that intentional?

Comment: No, this doesn't matter, I'll fix this

Comment: doing the check as `if task and task.done()` doesn't look like too bad of a check to me

Comment: Also, if you really feel it's boilerplate, you can move it to an appropriately named method, so the `if self._bla_task and self._bla_task.done()` becomes just `if self._bla_done()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is a language with [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing), so as long as some object can answer if it's `done()`, it should do the job:

```
class DummyTask:
    def done(self):
        return True


print(DummyTask().done())  # True
```

More smart way to do it is to use [mock library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).